# How do I submit a PUT method form in Laravel without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

This is my form html in my Laravel application:

```
 <button onclick="submitForm()">submit form using jquery ajax</button>
  <form name="fbCommentCountform" action="{{ route('blogs.update', ['id'=>$id]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    <input type="text" name="commentCount" id="fbFormCommentCount">
  </form>
```

This is the ajax Javascript code I am trying to use:

```
function submitForm() {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", "{{ route('blogs.update', ['id'=>$id]) }}", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var params = "search=";
  http.send(params);
  http.onload = function() {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
```

I'm a little confused on how I define my params to make it send the data in my id #fbFormCommentCount input box. I simply want the form to submit on button click without reloading the page and using a PUT method because it is for a update request in the controller. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't mind using jQuery either, I just need the form to submit without reloading the page, and send the one piece of data in the input field in the form with the id #fbFormCommentCount.

Comment: What about changing `http.open("POST"...` to `http.open("PUT",...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using jQuery's `.ajax()` like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $this.prop('action'),
        method: 'PUT',
        data: $this.serialize(),
    }).done(function(response){

    }).error(function(err){

    });
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` will keep the form from submitting and causing the page refresh.

Then just move your button into the form and give it a `type` of `submit`

```
<button type="submit"> Submit form using jquery ajax </button>
```

Comment: Not every frontend problem warrants the need to bring in jQuery. If the project doesn't already use jQuery, there's no good reason to load such a large library for such a tiny slice of functionality.

Comment: @LINKIWI Laravel ships with `jQuery` and `OP` specifically asked for it in the comments. Thank you, however.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is that a new feature? I don't remember Laravel shipping with jQuery before, maybe I just missed it.

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Love jQuery haha :D :D :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the values from your form, like so:

```
var commentCount = document.getElementById('fbFormCommentCount').value,
    params = "commentCount=" + commentCount;
```

You'll also need to grab and append your `_method` field, and the csrf token.  If they don't have IDs, you can grab them by name:

```
var method = document.getElementsByName('_method')[0].value,
    token = document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default event of the form submission.

Here's a minimal example of how to do it

https://jsfiddle.net/w208gsj7/1/

*HTML*

```
<form>
  <button type="submit"id="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

*JS*

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submitForm);

function submitForm(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  // ... code
}
```

Comment: The form is not actually being submitted.  There is no need to prevent it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You're right, didn't see the button outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I was able to submit a form in Laravel without reloading the page. I did this while using AngularJs and so had to put everything in a $(function(){}); like so:

```
$(function()
{
    $('form').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.prop('action'),
            method: 'POST',
            data: $this.serialize(),
            success: function(result)
            {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: Newer versions of JQuery use "success:" instead of ".done". Hope this helps someone using a newer version.